# boxClass for Google Maps not working?

Tags: google-maps

This is my google maps code that creates a marker's info window and limits its width to 200px. Everything works fine:

```
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                    infowindow.setOptions({maxWidth:200}); 
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                    });
```

Now I need to add a class to the infow window so I can style it with CSS. From the google maps documentation it seems boxClass is what I need but the following doesnt add the class. Do I have a syntax error?

```
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                    infowindow.setOptions({boxClass:'myGoogleClass'});
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use infowindow with boxClass. You must use the infoBox component instead.
If you change the infowindow to infobox it will work fine.

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: theMap,
         draggable: true,
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.47216, -123.76307),
         visible: true
        });

        var boxText = document.createElement("div");
        boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: yellow; padding: 5px;";
        boxText.innerHTML = "City Hall, Sechelt<br>British Columbia<br>Canada";

        var myOptions = {
                 content: boxText
                ,disableAutoPan: false
                ,maxWidth: 0
                ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
                ,zIndex: null
                ,boxStyle: { 
                  background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
                  ,opacity: 0.75
                  ,width: "280px"
                 }
                ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
                ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
                ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
                ,isHidden: false
                ,pane: "floatPane"
                ,enableEventPropagation: false
        };

        var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
        ib.open(theMap, marker);
```

Above code taken from [here](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html)

The only thing you can style when using infowindow is the content, not the window itself

Comment: All im trying to do is give my infowindow rounded corners. I assumed adding a class to it was the easiest way, but maybe not if I have to change my code a lot and add a new js file?

Comment: I don't think you have to make many changes. Just a few tweaks. But that's your call.